# Virtual box : How to copy/paste text between a host running mac os and a ubuntu guest? (Shared clipboard doesn't work)

Tags: virtualbox, 18.04

Shared Clipboard and Drag'n Drop both set to Bidirectional.

`Devices > Guest Additional CD image`   gives this error.

> Unable to insert the virtual optical disk
>   /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
>   into the machine Ubuntu_vm

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is simply to copy/paste text between host and guest, as an alternative to using the shared clipboard, you can achieve this by opening a port on the Virtual Machine & using ssh to login to the guest from a standard Mac OS terminal.

If you didn't install an ssh server on the guest you can add this like so from the (guest) command line

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ssh-server
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

If you are running ufw firewall you will need to allow ssh from the (guest) command line

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

You need to add a policy to the VM so that it will allow connections to the port, you can do this from the (host) command line:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "<my_ubuntu_vm>" --natpf1 "<name_for_your_rule>,tcp,,<alternative_port_for_ssh_eg_2222>,,22"
```

Then you can ssh into the guest from the (host) command line

```
ssh -p <alternative_port_for_ssh_eg_2222> <your_username_on_the_vm>@127.0.0.1
```

The host command line remains under the control of Mac OS so you can now cut and paste as you would from any other terminal &/or application

Comment: Update: if you want to run an `ubuntu` guest on a `mac os` host this got way simpler when ubuntu released [multipass](https://multipass.run/) which does exactly that, without need for Virtual Box. 

If you are running `multipass`then you can start a shell on the guest directly from the tray icon and cut + paste will work out of the box

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error when a disk was already inserted into the VM, such as the previous guest additions. Do you have another iso already attached?

Comment: I'm really new to this. In `Settings > Storage `
Under `Controller :IDE`

There is `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso`

Is this what you asked?. Also I just created the VM.

Comment: Yes, try removing that iso file then booting up your virtual machine and doing the "insert guest additions" option and see if it gives you the same error.

Comment: Did that. I get this error when I click `Devices > Guest addition CD image`.  Could not insert the /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxGuestAdidtions.iso disk image file into virtual machine Ubuntu as the machine has no optical drives . Please add a drive using storage page of the virtual machine settings window.

Comment: @Enzio With your VM  closed, you need to have it highlighted, then click Settings, click on Storage, then Controller: IDE, then below click on the Add New Storage Attachment and add an Optical Drive.